# Creating a new sap.m.Button in openui5 with Target="_blank" property

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to specify a new sap.m.Button to open a new window (equivalent  of target="_blank" for the link html tab) ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I you did just post it as a correct answer. Share the experience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing for a sap.m.Button out of the box, instead you should be using a Link. BUT, with simple JavaScript you could do the follow to achieve what is desired:

```
new sap.m.Button({
    text: "Hello World!",
    press: function() {
      window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
    }
  }
```